# How to use EEPlus License with Revit

Tags: c#, excel, epplus, revit-api

Im new to programming and i am trying to read and display excel data as a add in for revit 2022. I am using visual studio 2022 for this.  I figured out that i need the EEPlus package for the excel bit of the script. I dont understand how to reference that i am using the non commercial license?
Am i supposed to incorporate this in the script somehow?:

```
ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;

using(var package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo("MyWorkbook.xlsx")))
{

}
```

This is how my script is looking at the minute:

```
using Autodesk.Revit.DB;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Jada
{


    [Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.Transaction(Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.TransactionMode.ReadOnly)]
    public class ReadExcel : IExternalCommand
    {
        static AddInId appID = new AddInId(new Guid("D8822352-EC01-42AA-8165-714A26786540"));

        public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet        elementSet)
        {
            string filename = "";
            System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog openDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
            openDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            openDialog.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
            if (openDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                filename = openDialog.FileName;
            else
                return Result.Cancelled;

            string data = "";
            using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(filename)))
            {
                ExcelWorksheet sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
                for (int row = 1; row < 9999; row++)
                {
                    var thisValue = sheet.Cells[row, 1].Value;
                    if (thisValue == null || thisValue.ToString() == "")
                        break;

                    data += thisValue.ToString() + ",";
                    data += Environment.NewLine;
                }
            }
            TaskDialog.Show("Excel", data);

            return Result.Succeeded;
        }
    }
}
```

I have downloaded the EEPlus package in the NuGet package manager. I am also incorporating using OfficeOpenXml; in my script.

Answer (score 0):

You have some alternatives to configure the LicenseContext that is mandatory from version 5 of Epplus, according to the documentation [here](https://epplussoftware.com/docs/5.7/articles/readme.html).

The most practical way, in my opinion, for Asp Net Applications is configuring it in the appSettings.json file, as shown below:

```
{
    {
    "EPPlus": {
        "ExcelPackage": {
            "LicenseContext": "Commercial" or "NonCommercial"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You didn't say what kind of application you're developing (from the posted code it seems to be WPF). In this case, check in the documentation above what fits the type of your project.

Answer (score 0):

I have never written a plugin for Revit but I assume you can just set the license in a `static` constructor for the class, like any other:

```
static ReadExcel()
{
    ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You already solved it
you just need to add this line
`ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;`
before using the `ExcelPackege`

Here is how your code should look

```
using Autodesk.Revit.DB;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Jada
{


    [Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.Transaction(Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.TransactionMode.ReadOnly)]
    public class ReadExcel : IExternalCommand
    {
        static AddInId appID = new AddInId(new Guid("D8822352-EC01-42AA-8165-714A26786540"));

        public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet        elementSet)
        {
            string filename = "";
            System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog openDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
            openDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            openDialog.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
            if (openDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                filename = openDialog.FileName;
            else
                return Result.Cancelled;

            string data = "";
///Here is the added line
            ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
            using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(filename)))
            {
                ExcelWorksheet sheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
                for (int row = 1; row < 9999; row++)
                {
                    var thisValue = sheet.Cells[row, 1].Value;
                    if (thisValue == null || thisValue.ToString() == "")
                        break;

                    data += thisValue.ToString() + ",";
                    data += Environment.NewLine;
                }
            }
            TaskDialog.Show("Excel", data);

            return Result.Succeeded;
        }
    }
}
```